# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' flutter error

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I get the error:

> 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(widget.id);
    AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>? snapshot;
    Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot?.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: You arent passing anything on `snapshot` but using on next line

Comment: yes i dont want to pass anything

Comment: You didn't initialize `snapshot` so it's 
_null_ and on the next line you are trying to convert _null_ to _Map_, it won't work.

Comment: and where are you even using `snapshot` and `data`, it is only scoped inside `initState()`

Answer (score 2):

`snapshot?.data!.data()` evaluates to null because `snapshot` is null. And trying to cast it to a map with `as Map<String, dynamic>` throws this error.

To fix it use a ternary operator like that (assuming `data` should not be null):

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot?.data?.data() != null
  ? snapshot?.data!.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>
  : <String, dynamic>{};
```